# Python warning "'str' is not callable" when calling a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I am getting a warning on the line below stating that: 'str' object is not callable.

Is there anything I can do to make the warning go away?

Thanks

```
Action.action()
```

Here is the block of code:

```
Action = DefineAction()
Action.action()


class DefineAction:
    def action(self):
        self.action = listAction[generateRandomNumber(0,4)]
        return self.action
```

Here is listAction:

```
listAction =['walks','runs','jaunts','ambles','dashes','sprints']
```

Comment: What's `listAction`? Also, fix your indentation.

Comment: Oops sorry...I indented and added the listAction list.-thanks

Comment: This of course has nothing to do with Python 2.7 vs 3.3. Updated to that effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually more complicated than I initially thought, since you have a function named `self.action` **and** a variable named `self.action`, so your code is confusing. The first time you call `DefineAction.action()`, you overwrite the function with a string, so the second time you call it, you get this error.

Just give your function and variable different names and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `action`, you set `self.action` to a string.  This means that when you call `Action.action()` the first time it sets the attribute `Action.action` to a string, so the next time you call `Action.action()` you will see this error.

Just pick a different name for your attribute, make sure that it doesn't match the name of the method.  You could use `DefineAction.action(Action)` to still call the original `action()` method, but this is bad practice.